# How to write xpath for dynamic classes and check css property

Tags: css, xpath, cypress

I'm trying to automate a system developed using React and Sass. The automation tool is Cypress.
There are few issues I'm having with initiated work. Hence all the elements are using dynamic classes.

Question 1: Once there's a new build for frontend, all the classes will get changed.

AS for e.g:  if I write the following command

cy.get('.css-fdt4ua-Text-BettingAdd__Single').click();

fdt4ua    - > will get change with the new build.

After that my automation scripts will get fail and the whole automation scripts have to rewrite for new elements.Is it possible to use xpath to identify an element uniquely with the page HTML as following?

Since same class repeat again and again when I wrote relative xpath for a element, it is matching with multiple elements.

Try to perform click event on the following class. Class contains MID Div also dynamic value.

```
<span class="css-fdt4ua-Text-BettingAdd__Single ewp79e31" xpath="1">MID Div </span>
```

This is the xpath I wrote using ChroPath and it's found 16 elements match with this xpath.

//span[contains(@class,'BettingAdd__Single')]

Anyone can suggest me a better way to identify unique element without rewriting the HTML with IDs?

```
<li class="runner_35798501 ekk885d0 css-1ororew-ListItem-RaceSelectionsListItem e1vbyzvs0" xpath="1">
    <div class="css-pn8xrj-RaceSelectionsListItem__Wrapper ekk885d2">
        <div class="css-8cp37u">
            <div class="css-ej6d3p-RaceSelectionsDetails e1j851ih0">
                <div class="css-5jb77i-RaceSelectionsDetails__Silk e1j851ih1">
                    <div class="css-9pm5vz-RaceSelectionsDetails__SilkImage e1j851ih2"></div>
                    <div class="css-113z9a9-Text-RaceSelectionsDetails__LastStartsRow e1j851ih6">34</div>
                </div>
                <div class="css-x04caf-RaceSelectionsDetails__DetailsColumn e1j851ih5">
                    <div class="css-1eld9n9-Text-RaceSelectionsDetails__Name e1j851ih7">1. GIAAN'S GIRL
                        <span class="css-1nxtao7-Text e1j851ih8"> (1)
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="css-11nny5s-Text e1j851ih8">T: Wayne Gray</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div size="1" class="win_35798501 ekk885d5 css-1e6g9j6-BettingAdd ewp79e33">
            <span class="css-fdt4ua-Text-BettingAdd__Single ewp79e31">MID Div </span>
            <span class="css-e36q88-Text-BettingAdd__Multi ewp79e32">
                <i class="css-184tbjb-Icon e1ym0f420" title="add"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div size="1" class="place_35798501 ekk885d5 css-1e6g9j6-BettingAdd ewp79e33">
            <span class="css-fdt4ua-Text-BettingAdd__Single ewp79e31">MID Div </span>
            <span class="css-e36q88-Text-BettingAdd__Multi ewp79e32">
                <i class="css-184tbjb-Icon e1ym0f420" title="add"></i></span></div><div class="css-10y5zla">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Question 2: There are some

`<span class="css-fdt4ua-Text-BettingAdd__Single ewp79e31" xpath="1">MID Div </span>`

elements has been grey out on UI.

While executing the automation, those elements need to skip. The only difference in between the grey out and normal element is silk class `<div class="css-5jb77i-RaceSelectionsDetails__Silk e1j851ih1">` which belongs to grey out element is having CSS property as `opacity:0.2`

Is there a way to check the CSS property of silk class and perform the click element of BettingAdd__Single class?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the static version of website of you want to scrape the data but it will disable all the JS properties like buttons and all.
For scraping the data you can go to [www.scrapingdog.com](http://www.scrapingdog.com) and you can get a static page of react, redux based application in which the container class changes every session.
After getting the static page you can save it in ".html" file and run your automation script.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:
You can write the css locator in a way where you can match the part of the class name that doesn't change eg. `cy.get('[class*=Text-BettingAdd__Single]').click()`

Answer 2:
Since the class **div.silk**  is inside the class *Text-BettingAdd__Single* you can write something like

```
cy.get('[class*=Text-BettingAdd__Single]').parents().within(() => {
    cy.get('[class*=RaceSelectionsDetails__Silk').click()
})
```

Use `parent()` if you're going a single level up the DOM tree and Use `parents()` if you're going multiple levels up the DOM tree

Check out the cypress documentation - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parent.html#Syntax

Comment: Thanks mate. . Yes I can use locator in that way. But the thing is I need to check the Silk class property at the same time (Question 2). Need to skip CSS opacity property 0.2 classes

Comment: Just to clarify so you have an element like `div.silk` and inside the same div you have `div.BettingAdd__Single` and you only want to click those ?

Comment: `div.silk` is inside the sibling of `div.BettingAdd__Single` class.

`div.silk` class grand-grand parent is the parent of `div.BettingAdd__Single` class.